# DataSnap return empty dataset

Tags: android, delphi, datasnap, delphi-xe6

After more than a week's trial, I feel very depressed with DataSnap.

Today I again encountered a problem,

My Android(Java) client need to get a dataset from the DataSnap Server(XE6)，but the server return a empty result:

> {"result":[{"table":[]}]}

Here is the server code:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDataset(cmdstr: string): TDBXReader;
var
  CMD: TDBXCommand;
begin
  SQLConnection1.Open;
  CMD := SQLConnection1.DBXConnection.CreateCommand;
  CMD.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DbxSQL;
  CMD.Text := cmdstr;
  if not CMD.IsPrepared then
    CMD.Prepare;

  Result := CMD.ExecuteQuery;

  CMD.Free;  // If this line is commented out, it will memory leaks and return an exception.
end;
```

**[Update-----------------]**

Today I changed db access components to FireDAC:

```
{$METHODINFO ON}
  TServerMethods1 = class(TDataModule)
    Sqlite_demoConnection: TFDConnection;
    FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
    FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function EchoString(Value: string): string;
    function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
    function GetDataSet: TDataset;
  end;
{$METHODINFO OFF}


function TServerMethods1.GetDataSet: TDataset;
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, BirthDate from Employees';
  FDQuery1.Open();
  Result := FDQuery1;
end;
```

Delphi client can get the result and parse it. But Java client(Android) can't parse the result:

```
DSRESTConnection aConn = new DSRESTConnection();
DSProxy.TServerMethods1 aProxy = new DSProxy.TServerMethods1(conn);
aConn.setHost("192.168.0.240");
aConn.setPort(8080);
aConn.setProtocol("http");
try {
    TDataSet rd = aProxy.GetDataSet();

    int FieldCount = rd.getColumns().size();
    Log.i("FieldCount：", String.valueOf(FieldCount));  // get 4

    //rd.reset();
    while (rd.next())  // rd.next() get exception and return false
    {  
        Log.i("EmployeeID", rd.getValue("EmployeeID").GetAsString());
        Log.i("LastName", rd.getValue("LastName").GetAsString());

    }
} catch (DBXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update 2-------------------**

OK, I can got the result. Thank you MartynA and J__.

and I found why **rd.next()** return false:

The dataset which return from server, include a **datetime field**. DataSnap transform it to json:

```
"BirthDate":["1948-12-08.0","1952-02-19.0","1963-08-30.0"]
```

Every date value append with a ".0" tail.
So, Java can't transform back to Date type:

```
com.embarcadero.javaandroid.DBXException: Unparseable date: "1948-12-08.0" (at offset 10)
```

Then, I add a new server method to test return TDateTime type:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDateTime: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := int(Now);
end;
```

DataSnap also put it into the style below:

```
{"result":["2014-06-27.0"]}
```

Ooh, My god. How to fix this? on Server side? on Client side?

Comment: First thing is to try and isolate the problem, obviously.  Can you successfully retrieve the results of this query into a *Delphi* client?

Comment: Have you tried putting using a TDataset ancestor component on the ServerMethods form, and referencing that instead of having a local variable that is freed or loses scope when the function is complete? If you look at some of Marco Cantu's old white papers, you will see he returns TDataSet results from his Datasnap methods. I followed this method and it works perfectly.

Comment: +! for the self-help update.  FWIW, I've always found DataSnap itself quite easy to work with and highly reliable, though admittedly, when I was using the old-style version with the separate Scktsrvr utility to invoke the server rather than having that functionality built into the server per-se.  One DataSnap server I wrote clocked up several person-centuries of use at my workplace, with well over a million queries per year since D5 came out and hardly ever went wrong.