# Java can't parse the datetime value which from Datasnap server

Tags: java, delphi, datasnap

*This question derive from ["DataSnap return empty dataset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428075/datasnap-return-empty-dataset)
I think it is a another question, so I create a new thread in here.*

I write a DataSnap rest server which return a dataset with a TDateTime field.

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDataSet: TDataset;
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, BirthDate from Employees';
  FDQuery1.Open();
  Result := FDQuery1;
end;
```

But my android client(Java) can't parse the datetime value which get from server.

I tracking the Json data from server, and found the TDatetime type value:

```
"BirthDate":["1948-12-08.0","1952-02-19.0","1963-08-30.0"]
```

Every date value append with a ".0" tail. So, Java can't transform back to Date type:

Then, I add a new server method to test return TDateTime type:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetDateTime: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := int(Now);
end;
```

DataSnap also put it into the style below:

```
{"result":["2014-06-27.0"]}
```

So, How to fix this bug in Java client?

**[Update, A temporary solution]----------------------**

@BasilBourque, Thank you. You gave me some inspiration. I think it is a big workload If replace Java classes or class libraries. So I chose a simple solution.

Now, I fixed the Java code file "DBXDefaultFormatter.java" which automatically generated by  DataSnap server.

DBXDefaultFormatter.java, Line 257,
The original code:

```
public Date StringToDateTime(String value) throws ParseException {
    return datetimeFormatter.parse(value);
}
```

The fixed code:

```
public Date StringToDateTime(String value) throws ParseException {
    if ((value.length() == 12) & (value.endsWith(".0"))) {
        return dateFormatter.parse(value);
    } else {
        return datetimeFormatter.parse(value);
    }
}
```

I know, this is not a perfect solution, but it's basically will be enough.

Comment: That looks like a bug in `datasnap` .  Is the `.0` meant to mean something?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, it is not a bug. The result type is TDateTime, so the .0  represents the time fraction of that value. To get a date only one has to declare the result type as TDate. Regarding the dataset one has to select a proper field type to represent a date value only (depends on the database).

Comment: @UweRaabe Why on earth did DataSnap not use ISO-8601 text encoding when serializing TDateTime into JSON, or a plain floating point value of the corresponding double variable for transmission? If it is "not a bug, but a feature", sounds like a pretty much misconceived feature to me.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe, 1. DataSnap can't export(ProxyGenerator) TDate or TTime type. We will meet similar "2014-06-28 00:00:00" data when use TDatetime. Delphi client can parse it, But java can't. 2. We can't change the Table Field type to adapt this problem, This is not a sensible solution. 3. I think the best solution is to change the json content output from DataSnap, or let Java can accept the json content. But, I still can't fing out the fix entry.

Comment: Have you considered asking the vendor (RemObjects) to look into you error?

Comment: @Leo: I don't use JSON with Datasnap, otherwise I wouldn't have to ask, but couldn't one avoid this by using persistent TFields with the dataset and using the GetText event of the relevant field to format its string respresentation? Or does the JSON generation not use Fields' GetText events?

Comment: @Leo: Btw, here's an example I found of using DSO with DataSets which looks like it ought to be easy to modify for DateTime fields.  Tomorrow I'll have a look at the JSON demos which come with XE4.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include a link to the DSO example: http://www.techques.com/question/1-5973728/JUST-SHARE---Mysl-DataSet-into-Json-Format-using-delphi-SuperObject

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, Works In Java

You *can* parse those strings in Java using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

## Remove Offending Characters

One approach would be to strip off the last two characters.

```
String input = "1948-12-08.0";
String substring = input.substring( 0, 10 );
LocalDate localDateFromSubstring = new LocalDate( substring );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "substring: " + substring );
System.out.println( "localDateFromSubstring: " + localDateFromSubstring );
```

When run.

```
substring: 1948-12-08
localDateFromSubstring: 1948-12-08
```

## Tolerate Offending Characters

Another approach is to define a custom formatter that expects those last two characters. The formatter will throw an exception if not present. The single quote mark (APOSTROPHE-QUOTE) marks a sequence of literal characters, in our case `.0`.

```
String input = "1948-12-08.0";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'.0'" );
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( input );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );
```

When run.

```
input: 1948-12-08.0
localDate: 1948-12-08
```

---

You could probably do the same thing using the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. But those classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) new in Java 8.

Both Joda-Time and java.time provide a `LocalDate` class to represent a date-only without any time-of-day or time zone portion. The old Java classes do not.

As the comments on the question discuss, this format chosen by DataSnap is downright dumb. The problem here is with DataSnap, not Java. When serializing dates or date-times the obvious format for string representations is the sensible [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format. Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 as their default formats for both parsing and generating string representations.

Comment: +1 Technically it doesn't ignore the extra characters, it expects them and will error if they are not there.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for your thoughts. Incorporated into answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Thank you. You gave me some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps any but here's the code and DFM of a simple project which generates JSON from a dataset without including the '.0' you were getting (or the normally formatted Time part of a TDateTimeField value).

I thought it better to tackle the problem at source rather than in the client, especially as there may be more that one client implementation and a future one might not be in Java.

I don't know how you're currently generating your JSON and so mine probably isn't in quite the format you want, but anyway.

As I mentioned in a comment, you could do the processing of TDateTimeFields' string representation in the fields' GetText event, but that not produce what you want elsewherein your server (notice my grid includes the Time part of the string value);

```
function DataSetToJSONString(ADataSet : TDataSet): String;
var
  JSO,
  JSOOuter : TJsonObject;
  JSA : TJsonArray;
  JSP : TJsonPair;
  I,
  P : Integer;
  S : String;
  AField: TField;
Begin
  JSOOuter := TJsonObject.Create;
  JSA := TJsonArray.Create;
  JSP := TJSONPair.Create('CDS', JSA);
  JSOOuter.AddPair(jsp);

  ADataSet.DisableControls;
  ADataSet.First;
  try
    while not ADataset.Eof do
    begin
      JSO := TJsonObject.Create;
      for I := 0 to ADataSet.FieldCount - 1 do begin
        AField := ADataSet.Fields[I];
        case AField.DataType of
          ftBlob :
          begin
            raise Exception.Create('Unsupported field type');
          end;
          ftDateTime :
          begin
            S := AField.AsString;

            // check whether resulting string contains a space and truncate it 1 char before if so
            P := Pos(' ', S);
            if P > 0 then
              S := Copy(S, 1, P - 1);
          end
          else
            begin
              S := AField.AsString;
            end;
        end;
        JSO.AddPair(TJSonPair.Create(AField.FieldName, S));
      end;

      JSA.AddElement(JSO);
      ADataSet.Next;
    end;
  finally
    ADataSet.EnableControls;
    Result := JSOOuter.ToString;
    JSOouter.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.OpenDataSet;
begin
  if CDS.Active then
    CDS.Close;
  CDS.CreateDataSet;

  CDS.Insert;
  CDSName.AsString := 'Row ' + '"' + '1';    // to see what JSON does with double quotes embedded in data
  CDSDate.AsDateTime := Now;
  CDS.Post;

  CDS.Insert;
  CDSName.AsString := 'Row ' + '"' + '2';
  CDSDate.AsDateTime := Now;
  CDS.Post;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenDataSet;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DataSetToJSONString(CDS));
end;
```

DFM:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 304
  Top = 94
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 318
  ClientWidth = 758
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 26
    Top = 13
    Width = 705
    Height = 120
    DataSource = dsCDS
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 26
    Top = 168
    Width = 705
    Height = 129
    Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -13
    Font.Name = 'Courier New'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 271
    Top = 139
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object CDS: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    IndexFieldNames = 'ID'
    Params = <>
    Left = 48
    Top = 24
    object CDSID: TAutoIncField
      FieldName = 'ID'
    end
    object CDSName: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Name'
    end
    object CDSDate: TDateTimeField
      FieldName = 'Date'
    end
  end
  object dsCDS: TDataSource
    DataSet = CDS
    Left = 112
    Top = 24
  end
end
```